# Python Linear Regression Combination Problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I need to calculate the linear regression and the MSE in groups of two variables of my dataframe. The problem is that I can't compare the xtrain with two variables with the ytrain with one, but I just have a column in my ytrain.

Code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=3, n_targets=1, noise=0.01)
```

Problem:

```
from itertools import combinations
for c in combinations(range(4), 2):
    lr=LinearRegression()
    lr.fit(Xtrain[:,c].reshape(-1,1),ytrain)
    yp=lr.predict(Xtest[:,c].reshape(-1,1))
    print('MSE', np.sum((ytest - yp)**2) / len(ytest))
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the reshape method on the feature matrices as they are already two dimensional. If you remove the reshaping your code will work, see below.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=3, n_targets=1, noise=0.01, random_state=42)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

for c in combinations(range(4), 2):

    lr = LinearRegression()
    lr.fit(X_train[:, c], y_train)
    yp = lr.predict(X_test[:, c])

    print('MSE', np.sum((y_test - yp) ** 2) / len(y_test))

# MSE 591.707619290734
# MSE 33.613143724590564
# MSE 634.3248475857874
# MSE 1646.9447686107499
# MSE 2293.2878076807942
# MSE 1700.2559702871085
```